# How to add product in wishlist without redirecting to wishlist page

Tags: magento, magento2, magento-2.3

if we click on "add to wish list" button, it's displaying the "WISHLIST" page.

I don't want to display the wishlist page. instead of that, I want to be on the same page. but the item should

"add to wishlist".

please help me to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should customize the process of Magento add to the wishlist.
Magento using `dataPost.js` for posting form of wishlist.

You can change to use ajax to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the Add Controller of Wishlist Module and change the redirect URL to current URL :

Create a Module for example Wishlist/Example

etc/di.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
   <preference for="Magento\Wishlist\Controller\Index\Add" type="Wishlist\Example\Controller\Index\Add">
    </preference>
 </config>
```

Under Controller/Index/Add.php file :

```
<?php
 
namespace Wishlist\Example\Controller\Index;
 
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey\Validator;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NotFoundException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
 
/**
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 */
class Add extends \Magento\Wishlist\Controller\Index\Add
{
    /**
     * Adding new item
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect
     * @throws NotFoundException
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedLocalVariable)
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
        if (!$this->formKeyValidator->validate($this->getRequest())) {
            return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/');
        }
 
        $wishlist = $this->wishlistProvider->getWishlist();
        if (!$wishlist) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Page not found.'));
        }
 
        $session = $this->_customerSession;
 
        $requestParams = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
 
        if ($session->getBeforeWishlistRequest()) {
            $requestParams = $session->getBeforeWishlistRequest();
            $session->unsBeforeWishlistRequest();
        }
 
        $productId = isset($requestParams['product']) ? (int)$requestParams['product'] : null;
        if (!$productId) {
            $resultRedirect->setPath('*/');
            return $resultRedirect;
        }
 
        try {
            $product = $this->productRepository->getById($productId);
        } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
            $product = null;
        }
 
        if (!$product || !$product->isVisibleInCatalog()) {
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(__('We can\'t specify a product.'));
            $resultRedirect->setPath('*/');
            return $resultRedirect;
        }
 
        try {
            $buyRequest = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject($requestParams);
 
            $result = $wishlist->addNewItem($product, $buyRequest);
            if (is_string($result)) {
                throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(__($result));
            }
            if ($wishlist->isObjectNew()) {
                $wishlist->save();
            }
            $this->_eventManager->dispatch(
                'wishlist_add_product',
                ['wishlist' => $wishlist, 'product' => $product, 'item' => $result]
            );
 
            $referer = $session->getBeforeWishlistUrl();
            if ($referer) {
                $session->setBeforeWishlistUrl(null);
            } else {
                $referer = $this->_redirect->getRefererUrl();
            }
 
            $this->_objectManager->get(\Magento\Wishlist\Helper\Data::class)->calculate();
 
            $this->messageManager->addComplexSuccessMessage(
                'addProductSuccessMessage',
                [
                    'product_name' => $product->getName(),
                    'referer' => $referer
                ]
            );
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(
                __('We can\'t add the item to Wish List right now: %1.', $e->getMessage())
            );
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addExceptionMessage(
                $e,
                __('We can\'t add the item to Wish List right now.')
            );
        }
 
        $resultRedirect->setUrl($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl());
        return $resultRedirect;
    }
}
```

Here in the Controller all we change is

```
$resultRedirect->setPath('*', ['wishlist_id' => $wishlist->getId()]);
```

By

```
$resultRedirect->setUrl($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl());
```